# Django EmailMultiAlternatives with Embadded Image in HTML

Tags: python, django, email

I am trying to send email with HTML and embadded image. Email sending working fine and its also attaching the image in email but its not showing the image in HTML (inline). I used Content:ID in view and cid in template but no success :(. I explore so many forms and apply solutions but in vain please help!. Here is my code:

```
html_content = render_to_string('newsletters/newsletter_template.html', vars)
text_content = strip_tags(html_content) 

to = 'myemail@gmail.com'


msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(self.subject, text_content, settings.STAFF_FROM_EMAIL, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")

image_file = open('../media/images/banner_admin.gif', 'rb')
msg_image = MIMEImage(image_file.read())
image_file.close()

msg_image.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>')
msg.attach(msg_image)

msg.send()
```

## Template File:

```
<div style="border:2px solid #CCCCCC; width:900px; font-size:10px; padding:5px;">
    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><img src="cid:image1" /></div>
    <div style="">{{body|linebreaks}}</div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if I am missing something here...

Comment: Hi. Your code is working for me. I have received a formatted email with GMail and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

To Embed PNG file in body of email, try this code:

```
for f in ['img1.png', 'img2.png']:
    fp = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), f), 'rb')
    msg_img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    msg_img.add_header('Content-ID', '<{}>'.format(f))
    msg.attach(msg_img)

msg.send()
```

Now you can use `<img src="cid:img1.png">` in your template. The result should be that the email client shows the image embedded in the mail at the place of the `<img>` tag and not as an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Code examples adopted from this blog

HTML template code

```
<!-- BODY -->
<table class="body-wrap">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
             <div class="content">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {% for view in views %}
                                <h3>{{ view }}</h3>
                                <p><img src="cid:{{ view.image_filename }}" /></p>
                                {% if not forloop.last %}<p>&nbsp;</p>{% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table><!-- /BODY -->
Image table will be rendered as such:

<img src="cid:20161010_dailykpisnapshot_OCuZ4O4.png">
Views.py
import os
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string


rendered_report = RenderedReport.objects.get(pk=1)
views = rendered_report.rendered_views.all()

context = {'views': views}

html_content = render_to_string('reports/email.html', context=context).strip()

subject = 'HTML Email'
recipients = ['john.doe@test.com']
reply_to = ['noreply@test.com']

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, html_content, config.formatted_email_from, to, reply_to=reply_to)
msg.content_subtype = 'html'  # Main content is text/html
msg.mixed_subtype = 'related'  # This is critical, otherwise images will be displayed as attachments!

for view in views:
    # Create an inline attachment
    image = MIMEImage(view.png.read())
    image.add_header('Content-ID', '<{}>'.format(view.image_filename))
    msg.attach(image)

    # Create a regular attachment with a CSV file
    if view.csv:
        filename = os.path.basename(view.csv.name)
        msg.attach(filename, view.csv.read(), 'text/csv')

    # Create a regular attachment with a PDF file
    if view.pdf:
        filename = os.path.basename(view.pdf.name)
        msg.attach(filename, view.pdf.read(), 'application/pdf')

msg.send()
```

Email headers will look like this:

Content-Type: image/png
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <20161010_dailykpisnapshot_OCuZ4O4.png>
In production
In production it may be better to reference the image from your S3 source. In this case, no other backend work is needed in views.py, and simply include the S3 url of the target image.